# Using a custom pipe as a search filter on a table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I have this table with data inside of it. Now I want to implement a search bar that filters the table after the searches. To do this I assume I will need to use a pipe to filter the searches out. However this does not work for me and I don't know how this is possible to do.

The data inside of the tables comes from a locally stored json file under assets. The table is written out in the app.compinent.html file.

I've created a pipe but I do not know what the code inside of it should be.

Here's an example of what i'm trying to accomplish but the instead the data is in a table which takes it data from a locally stored file.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ujgcy

my code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
  name: 'countrysearch'
})


export class CountrysearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(Country: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if(!Country) return [];
    if(!searchText) return Country;
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
return Country.filter( it => {
      return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
   }
}
```

//html

```
<input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="search text goes here">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let country of Countries | filter : searchText">
        {{countries.Name}}
        </li>
    </ul>


    <table border="1">
        <!-- ADD HEADERS -->
        <tr>
            <th>>Name</th>
            <th>People</th>

<tr *ngFor="let country of Countries ">
            <td>{{ country.Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ country.People }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so whats the issue?

Comment: It doesn't work I'm not sure what's wrong, I get 0 results what so ever. When I take the data from the table instead it doesn't work.

Comment: your example is working, what is the problem?

Comment: Instead of taking the data like the example does, I want to take it from a locally saved json file. The filter is going to filter out in a table where the data is written out

Comment: so whats the big deal in getting the data from json? what have you tried?

Comment: that's the thing I don't know why it's not taking the data, do I have to write something specific to get the data in the pipe?

Comment: provide your code to find out whats not working

Comment: Updated my code sir

Comment: I'd like to note that everything is linked in app module etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because your pipe name is **countrysearch** but in your html file you have written `filter: searchText` It should instead be `countrysearch: searchText`

Else in your pipe.ts change the name to `filter` Instead of `countrysearch`

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, Now I get in the console "AppComponent.html:9 ERROR TypeError: it.toLowerCase is not a function" Do you have any idea on what this might imply?

Comment: Write it as `it.toString().toLowerCase()` in the return statement where you currently have `it.toLowerCase()`

Comment: When I do this it gives 0 errors in the console. But it makes the search results dissapear the table goes on and shows 0 results as fast as I type

Comment: Solved your code at [editor link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ujgcy) you just have to go to the pipe.filter.ts code and add `return it.Name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchText);` in place of return `it.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchText);` It was filtering the whole object instead of just the Name

Comment: It's okay, we all are learning :) You can mark the answer you feel appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

After posting your code as Richard mentioned you should change your Pipe to countrysearch as follows,

```
  <li *ngFor="let country of Countries | countrysearch : searchText">
        {{countries.Name}}
 </li>
```

and modify your pipe with null handling inorder and property filtering **`Name`** to avoid any errors as follows,

```
export class CountrysearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(Country: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if(!Country) return [];
    if(!searchText) return Country;
    if(Country && Country.length > 0){
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
return Country.filter( it => {
      return it.Name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, now I get the error "TypeError: it.toLowerCase is not a function"

Comment: When I type in the search field everything removes, it deletes everything but I get 0 errors

Comment: as i mentioned above reproduce your issue via stackblitz

Comment: "It's a pretty big project" I don't think it will be possible

Comment: dude the actual answer is in mine.